# "This application requires a java runtime 1.8" when using wine

Tags: java, linux, java-8, wine

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.14.16-arch1-1
- Java: java-8-openjdk
- DE: Xfce 4.16

When trying to launch .exe file with **Wine** on my Arch Linux I get this error: `This application requires a java runtime 1.8`.
The problem is that I already have this version of java installed under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/bin/java`.

I do have `jre8-openjdk` package installed on my system.

The output of `$ archlinux-java status`:

```
Available Java environments:
  java-17-openjdk
  java-8-openjdk (default)
```

The output of `& java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

There is also an issue with .jar file of the same program not opening, although it might be a problem with this specific program. Nothing happens when I try opening it with what presumably is installed Java 8. Although, when I try to open it with Java 17 it gives this error: [image: error]

Both .exe and .jar executables can be downloaded here: https://elician.ru/start

Comment: I think this belongs on `SuperUser`? This is definitely not a coding problem.

Comment: Oh, yea, I guess. I always forget about that site.

Comment: Can you perhaps show the CLI command you use when trying to run the Jar where "nothing happens"? Also, include echo statements that show the required environment variables are operative? The most recent mix-up I had with a similar configuration issue was when I had environment variables defined at my regular user level, but mistakenly tried to run the program as SUDO. Not saying that is happening for you, but with more info we could perhaps get some additional ideas about what is going on.

Comment: `$ java Elician.jar` ouputs `Error: Could not find or load main class Elician.jar`. What are the "echo statements that show the required environment variables are operative"?

Comment: These are all my Environment Variables if that what helps: https://pastebin.com/tAh4XEec

Comment: Am I missing something here? The original question of how to use your existing java installation from Wine doesn't appear to be answered. I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[/path/to/]java -jar jarfile` worked perfectly.
Solved.